# Cannot resolve symbol ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm trying to get the last known location in Android.
I've got this :

```
public int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

It works. But right after I have :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

which doesn't works.

Android studio says:

> Cannot resolve symbol checkSelfPermission()

I don't understand why.

Comment: probably you are referring to an anonymous class with `this` and you just need MainActivity.this

Comment: If you're using `this` from anonymous inner class, it will refer that inner class. so you need to explicitly use the reference of activity as `MainActivity.this`. Sometimes handling runtime permissions can be tricky, for which I have prepared a library at https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions You can try this library and save your time. ;)

Comment: Does your Activity extend AppCompactActivity?

Comment: Thanks Nabin, I'll try it now.
@LiJianixn Of course it does !

Answer (score -1):

Use `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,<permission>);`

Comment: **Nice example of [Million Monkeys Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)** ... `ActivityCompat` has no `checkSelfPermission` ... `checkSelfPermission` is in fact `ContextCompat's` method (and ActivityCompat is derived from ContextCompat) ... **it will obviously will not help!**

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

{//Permission Granted}

Comment: **Nice example of [Million Monkeys Programming Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)** ... `ActivityCompat` has no `checkSelfPermission` ... `checkSelfPermission` is in fact `ContextCompat's` method (and ActivityCompat is derived from ContextCompat) ... **it will obviously will not help!**

Comment: @Selvin thanks a lot for your review but please first you should have guts and concepts to give answer rather than to find the mistakes in someone's....

Comment: *first you should have guts and concepts to give answer rather than to find the mistakes in someone's* No, i don't have to ... answer is obvious(`this` is not a `Context`) ... and this is not a valid answer ... (but example of Million Monkeys Programming Style)